# How is the avagadros constant derived?

Tags: physical-chemistry

İ heard that : 
Charge of a mole of electrons/charge of single electron =avagadros constant 
How is this derived ?

Comment: What is a mole, come to think of it?

Comment: Charge of a mole of electrons is the Faraday electrolysis constant. So the Avogadro constant can be measured in an electrolysis experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to determine the charge of a *mole* of electrons vs the charge of *one* electron.

We get the charge of one electron from the [Milliken oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment).

For a mole of electrons you can start uf you firzt get the molar mass of water, call this $18.016$ grams per mole.  Now electrolyze water with an inert electrolyte such as sodium sulfate.  Work out the charge transfer required to decompose one mole = $18.016$ grams.  This is two moles of electrons based on the stoichiometry of the electrochemical reaction.  Half of this divided by the single electron charge is Avogadro's number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the number of carbon atoms in 12 grams.

Comment: How do you count the atoms?

Comment: OP meant his specific calculation with electrons.